# Cronbach's Alpha low- significant results

Tags: statistical-significance, reliability, consistency, cronbachs-alpha

One of my variables has a low Cronbach's Alpha. I continued to run an planned contrast to test my hypothesis and the results were significant.

I understand that the results should be interpreted lightly. My question is however, what does it mean if the Cronbach's Alpha is low yet significant results have been found?

Answer (score 1):

[Cronbach's alpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronbach's_alpha) measures [internal consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_consistency). Low alpha indicates that the variable comprises unrelated, or 'weakly related', items. How low is Cronbach's alpha for your variable? In cases of very low internal consistency, a 'significant result' (what did you test?) may not be interpretable as reflecting a significant effect over all variable items, but only over a specific fraction of them. Furthermore, if items are unrelated a 'positive' change in some of them may be masked by a 'negative' change in unrelated others.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, it means a lot to me. I was testing whether individuals feel culturally similar to those I had within a scenario, and whether that affected their ethical decision-making (i.e., if they felt culturally similar to those in the scenario, did it cause them to think the scenario was more unethical?). The Cronbach's alpha was .566. I had used existing scale items.